# springapplication.run is creating multiple connected clients

Tags: java, spring

I am doing this:

```
    final String[] args = new String[0];
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MianClass.class);
    springApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = springApplication.run(args);
```

And after last line I see I have created 20 connections to mySQL database. And next when I do some query it use only 1 User.

What could be the reason for creating so many clients?

Comment: You probably configured the connection pool to have 20 connections. What you describe is how a connection pool works.

Comment: The pool configuration is generally in the `application.properties`m, for a Spring Boot application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have one more question, are you able to tell me what could be the reason that someone set maximumPoolSize = 20? Or why do it set this to greater than 1?

Comment: Do you want to be able to handle 1 request concurrently? Or do you only want a single thread being able to process something. Why it is 20 you should ask the person who build it. How manu to use, depends on the type of application, generally 1 is too little and becomes a bottleneck.